# How should I properly format my iPod nano 5th generation?

Tags: disk-utility, music, ipod, disk-format, ipod-nano

I've been the happy owner of an iPod nano 5th gen, 8Gb for a few years.
Over the years, I've added and deleted many songs, lyrics, album art, etcetera, and I recently assumed that something was corrupted in the drive: when I would add new album artwork to a song, it would either not work or add the album art of one song to a lot of other totally unrelated songs.

This [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/message/17776595#17776595) is excellent to start troubleshooting, but didn't really help on a iPod nano (*diagnostics mode* is limited on this model).

*Permissions Repair* (or actually "*First Aid*" as it is now called) didn't find anything.

So I backed up all the songs I had on the it to my MBP. I also checked that the files were not corrupted.

I would like to restore the device the best possible way, before I put the tracks back on it.

When I launched the (brand-new) El Capitan's *Disk Utility*, there was a new setting I hadn't seen in previous versions, called "scheme".

[image]

The options are:

1. GUID Partition Map
2. Master Boot Record
3. Apple Partition Map

I'm not really sure which one to use for an iPod nano, and couldn't find anything online.

Comment: From all this I understand that you would like to reset your device.Am I right ?

Comment: Restore it in iTunes, not Disk Utility. If I could find my old iPod, I'd add an answer with pics...

Comment: @Tetsujin could you expand your comment into an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle an iPod Restore is to do it from iTunes.

iTunes knows what it is & how to format it - it will even actually format differently depending on whether you have iTunes on a PC or Mac, to enable easier file handling afterwards.

- If it's a model with a lock switch at the top [red dot visible] switch the lock off first [white dot] - Some models will crash if you don't.
- Plug it into the computer, launch iTunes if it doesn't launch automatically.
- Click the device icon in the top bar, choose the iPod if you see multiple devices listed.
- Click Restore. Follow the onscreen instructions.
  You will need to resync afterwards.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the command line to format your device, this did the trick for me on a 4th gen Nano :

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ mydiskname diskX
```

- with "mydiskname" being your personal choice, and
- X to be replaced by the corresponding device number.

The latter you can determine via

```
diskutil list
```

You might also first have to unmount the device with

```
diskutil unmount [force] diskX
```

The "force" option may not be always necessary, so you might be able to leave it out. (But I figured, since the goal is to blank the device anyhow, a force should not hurt too much.)

Good look! It took me a while. Nothing I found online seemed to work out for me. So I finally went down trying the trusted old diskutil command, worked like a charm. The nano was immediately recognized in iTunes.